# jquery load() dynamic content not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, load

i have a website with several tiles that, when clicked, should load a specific piece of content into another div on the site. the content is on a php page referenced by an "id" that i store in each tile's "rel" attribute. for example:

```
<div id="tile" rel="1">tile 1 preview content</div>
<div id="tile" rel="2">tile 2 preview content</div>
<div id="tile" rel="3">tile 3 preview content</div>
```

here's the jquery i am trying to make accomplish this:

```
$('#tile').on('click', function(){
    var projectId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#projectLoad').load('project.php?id='+projectId);
});
```

can anyone help me figure out why it's not working? thanks!

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Errors?  No results?  Where is #projectLoad?  Are you sure project.php is returning what you think it is?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any other information. Could you post the full HTML/JS for a minimal example?

Comment: are you able to see the response in console ?

Comment: **ID's must be unique**, and you aren't using the event delegation form of `.on`, therefore it will only target current elements.

Comment: sorry for the confusion and thanks for the quick help. there is, of course, a div on the page (only one) with the id "projectLoad". when i say it is not working, it is simply not loading anything. i have tested project.php and it works exactly as i intend it to.

Comment: kevin b- can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, all of the divs have the same id.  Id's must be unique.  Does your code work if you give them each a unique id?

```
<div id="tile1" rel="1">tile 1 preview content</div>
<div id="tile2" rel="2">tile 2 preview content</div>
<div id="tile3" rel="3">tile 3 preview content</div>

$('#tile1').on('click', function(){
    var projectId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#projectLoad').load('project.php?id='+projectId);
});

$('#tile2').on('click', function(){
    var projectId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#projectLoad').load('project.php?id='+projectId);
});

$('#tile3').on('click', function(){
    var projectId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#projectLoad').load('project.php?id='+projectId);
});
```

**NOTE** to test this functionality you can try this jQuery code:

```
$('#tile1').on('click', function(){ alert('hello from div 1'); });
$('#tile2').on('click', function(){ alert('hello from div 2'); });
$('#tile3').on('click', function(){ alert('hello from div 3'); });
```

As Palash mentioned in his answer, you can avoid this duplication by using class instead of id. (Classes do not have to be unique.)

```
<div class="tile" rel="1">tile 1 preview content</div>
<div class="tile" rel="2">tile 2 preview content</div>
<div class="tile" rel="3">tile 3 preview content</div>

$('.tile').on('click', function(){
    var projectId = $(this).attr('rel');
    alert('hello from div ' + projectId);
})
```

Here is a jsFiddle showing this simple test - http://jsfiddle.net/RHXGS/

**Another, self-contained, test added from the comments**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Click Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.div1').on('click', function () {
                    alert('Click!');
                    $('#div2').html('content');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="div1">click me</div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: this did not work. i even added in an alert: alert('Click!'); in the function, but i'm not getting an alert.

Comment: Did you notice that I only added the jQuery for the first div "tile1"?  So the click event will only fire on that one div.  With unique id's you will need to add the jQuery for each id individually.  I will update my answer with the jQuery for the other divs to avoid confusion.

Comment: yes- i targeted my test toward tile1, as you did. i also targeted several different tiles as you did in your second example, and still no alert.

Comment: If you are not getting an alert then some other code that you have not shared with us is causing a conflict.  Here is a jsFiddle showing the test, http://jsfiddle.net/RHXGS/

Comment: i'm currently seeking out the conflict. in the meantime, i am trying a much simpler example:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Click Test</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.div1').on('click', function(){
 alert('Click!');
 $('#div2').html('content');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="div1">click me</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
</body>
</html>

this works on fiddle, however it doesn't work when i save it as an html and load it in a browser. i'm doing something wrong elsewhere and i just can't see it. can you?

Comment: If you wrap your test code in `$(document).ready` (to wait for the DOM to load) it will work.  I will add this test to my answer since code in these comments is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id like from this:

```
<div id="tile" rel="1">tile 1 preview content</div>
<div id="tile" rel="2">tile 2 preview content</div>
<div id="tile" rel="3">tile 3 preview content</div>
```

to this;

```
<div class="tile" rel="1">tile 1 preview content</div>
<div class="tile" rel="2">tile 2 preview content</div>
<div class="tile" rel="3">tile 3 preview content</div>
```

and js code like this:

```
$('.tile').on('click', function(){
    var projectId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#projectLoad').load('project.php?id='+projectId);
});
```

You will get a `projectId` each time you click on the div this time and load will work.
Please always try to use unique IDs in HTML markup.

Comment: this is not working. do you have any ways to troubleshoot this? i added an alert inside the function to test if the page is detecting the click, but no alert is coming up.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to load the content into a div with an ID of "#projectload". There is no div in your code with that ID.